# Replace returned null values in LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, join, null, outer-join

```
SELECT        WO_BreakerRail.ID, indRailType.RailType, indRailType.RailCode, WO_BreakerRail.CreatedPieces, WO_BreakerRail.OutsideSource, WO_BreakerRail.Charged, WO_BreakerRail.Rejected, WO_BreakerRail.RejectedToCrop, WO_BreakerRail.Date
FROM            indRailType LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         WO_BreakerRail ON indRailType.RailCode = WO_BreakerRail.RailCode AND WO_BreakerRail.Date = @date
```

When this returns, there are NULL values in the Date column where there are no matching rows from WO_BreakerRail. Is there a way to replace just those NULL values with @date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In oracle and sql server, you can use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) ([oracle version](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)) function

```
SELECT ...., COALESCE(WO_BreakerRail.Date, @date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE` function (go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for mysql documentation)

```
COALESCE(WO_BreakerRail.Date, @date)
```

or you can use a simple IF:

```
IF(WO_BreakerRail.Date IS NULL, @date, WO_BreakerRail.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `COALESCE`, eg. `COALESCE(WO_BreakerRail.Date, @date)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in MySQL there is a IFNULL() function.

```
select
  ifnull(wo_breakerrail.date, @date) as `date`,
```