# Linq Left outer join replace null values returned

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am sure this has been discussed before but I read several LINQ left outer join posts and couldn't figure out whether it has been discussed or not. The closest thread that matched what I was looking for is [Replace returned null values in LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507300/replace-returned-null-values-in-left-outer-join?rq=1), but its not LINQ related.

Now on to my question, my query does left outer join with DefaultIfEmpty(). Here's an example query I grabbed from another post for illustration

```
from adx_event in Adx_eventSet
join adx_eventsponsor in adx_eventsponsor_eventSet
on adx_event.Adx_eventId equals adx_eventsponsor.adx_eventid into j 
from adx_eventsponsor in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{ 
 Name = adx_event.Name,
 Name = adx_eventsponsor != null ? adx_eventsponsor.Name : null  
};
```

In the above query, if adx_eventsponsor returns null, then the check "on adx_event.Adx_eventId equals adx_eventsponsor.adx_eventid into j" is failing with Null reference exception. How to handle this issue?

Here's the query I am working with, sorry its a lengthy one with 5 left joins

```
from t1 in table1List
join t2 in table2List on t1.ID equals t2.fID
join m in DataAccess.Data.table3List on t2.ID equals m.ID into fg
from fgi in fg.Where(m => m.Year == reportYear).DefaultIfEmpty()
join c1 in table4List on t2.ID equals c1.ID into t4
from c1 in t4.Where(c1 => c1.Year == reportYear && c1 != null).DefaultIfEmpty()
join c2 in table4List  on t2.ID equals c2.ID into t5
from c2 in t5.Where(c2 => c2.Year == reportYear - 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
join fA in table5List on t2.ID equals fA.ID into t6
from fA in t6.Where(fA => fA.Year == reportYear).DefaultIfEmpty()
join src in table6List on new { ID = fA != null ? fA.sourceID : 
new Guid("    {ccae20792ebc-4200-879d-866fc82e6afa}"), Year = reportYear } equals new 
{ ID = Src.ID, Year = Src.Year } into t7 from Src in t7.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

My question is in the last left outer join where if fA (from table5List) returns null, I can't do a join on fA.sourceID, so I am explicitly hardcoding a Guid to avoid that null exception. What is a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help!